# Meaning of "...would not be coming to America, ... be risking the most important national security arrangement that Israel has if it wasn't for..."

Tags: meaning, phrases

> In the end, Prime Minister Netanyahu would not be coming to America,
>   he would not be risking the most important national security
>   arrangement that Israel has if it wasn't for the fact that he believed in his heart that Iran's and the United States` nuclear negotiating is
>   going to end up being an existential threat to his country. —[CNN Student News](http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1503/02/sn.01.html)

I read this sentence several times, but I can't grasp the meaning of it. The structure is too complicated. Could you help me understand this sentence?

My guess: In the end, Prime Minister will come to America nevertheless the visit can risk the most important national security arrangement (which is, I guess, the amicable relationship between the U.S and Israel), because the negotiation can be a serious threat to his country and he wants to stop it.

Comment: This is a quote from Rich Santorum, ex-Senator from Pennsylvania, ex-Presidential candidate, and an 11 on the Richter idiocy scale.  I wouldn't bother trying to parse the syntax.  Republicans invited Netanyahu to address Congress to attack the policies of  the sitting President, which basically made Netanyahu a suborner of sedition.  Santorum is saying that Netanyahu wouldn't have done something so dire if he didn't think the President's policy of negotiating with Iran held the real possibility of destroying Israel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prime Minister Netanyahu would not be coming to America:

> *He is coming to America*

(Actually, he came and addressed Congress, which angered Obama and the Department of State as his visit was arranged by the Republicans in order to derail the nuclear negotiation with Iran).

he would not be risking the most important national security arrangement that Israel has:

> *He is risking the most important national security arrangement that Israel has.*

(Israel's most important national security arrangement is the one with the U.S., and Netanyahu thinks stopping the nuclear deal is more important than a possibility that his visiting and addressing *uninvited by the White House* can worsen the relationship and arrangement with the U.S.)

if it wasn't for the fact that he believed in his heart that Iran's and the United States` nuclear negotiating is going to end up being an existential threat to his country:

> It is the fact that he believes in his heart that ....

If you find such sentences written in the *subjunctive mood*, it is easier to understand them by changing the mood to the *indicative mood*, from a *negative* sentence to a *positive* sentence and vice versa.